# Triply transitive action on upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, hyperbolic-geometry

I am calculating the area of a triangle in the upper half  plane. Consider the following triangle in the upper half plane with the Poincare metric.

[image]

Can I transform this triangle to the following triangle via an element of $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$?

[image]

I have the above doubt. I think I can do this because $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ triple transitively on boundary of the upper half plane, which is  $\Bbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right, that you can map any hyperbolic triangle with all vertices on $\mathbb R\cup \{i\infty\}$ to any other, by the action of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$.

For me, it's clearest to do it in steps, and to map to the hyperbolic triangle with vertices $0,1,i\infty$. Namely, given such a triangle, map any vertex to $i\infty$. Then translate so that the left-most vertex on the real line is moved to $0$. The dilate to move the right-most vertex to $1$.

So, yes, semi-amazingly, all their hyperbolic areas are the same. :)

Comment: If your comment is intended to ask whether the action is doubly-transitive on the hyperbolic two-space itself: no, it is not. In the disk model, the automorphisms fixing $0$ are just rotations, which have infinitely-many orbits (the circles centered at $0$). This uses Schwarz' lemma.

Comment: Sorry for the previous  comment. I made typo there. I am asking:  Does $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ act doubly transitive on $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$?

Comment: Well, apparently, triply-transitively, as in your original question, and as explicated in my "answer".

Comment: In your answer all the three vertices are in $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$. But in my next question I have added, there only two vertices are on $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$. So, my question is:  Does $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ act doubly transitive on $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$? Is it happens then I can do transform the following. Is it correct?

Comment: Ah, you should re-pose your second question, not as an "answer" to your first, but as a separate question. That is the style here. I'll wait to see that separate/new question. :)

Comment: A you advised I have asked the question as a new post.